# windows open - why link are opening differently - in new tab and new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

*When i use this code, link open in new window(**Code 1**):*

```
$.post("test.php", {
...
...
...
},
function(data){
var data = data; //data = 32@4http://google.com
var arr=data.split("@4");
var link = arr[1]; //link=http://google.com
window.open(arr[1], "_blank"); //link open in new window

});
```

*But link open in new tab when i use next code(**Code 2**):*

```
$.post("test.php", {
...
...
...
},
function(data){
var data = data;
window.open($("link").attr("href"), "_blank"); //link open in new tab

});
```

*Tell me please why link are opening differently in code 1 and code 2 and how make that in code1 link are opened in new tab?*

Comment: Alert(arr[1]); Alert($("link").attr("href")); can help you solve the problem.. are that the same?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco `Alert(arr[1]); Alert($("link").attr("href"));` show one link - this first that i make.

Comment: more interesting: http://jsfiddle.net/QFHuJ/

Comment: I think it's due to the fact that `.post` returns `data`. but why ?

Answer (score 1):

There is really no difference between these two lines of code. Most likely you tested this in two different browsers?

More important: You cannot influence, how a window is opened. That is up to the user (browser). If the user chooses to open in a new tab or new window or in the same window you can do nothing about this.

Yes, you can specify `_blank` but this is only a recommendation, the user's choice (= the browser setting) always has precedence. That's why you should not bother how or why your window opens in a way.

Comment: no - i test in one browser and i get difference open in one browser.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code and both of the links open in a new tab for me. (See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAMZp/).) It depends on the browser and the settings you are using. Firefox for example has an option "open new tab instead of window".

**HTML:**

```
<a id="open">open</a>

<a id="link" href="http://google.com"></a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var link = "http://google.com";

document.getElementById('open').onclick = function () {
    window.open(link, "_blank");
    window.open($('#link').attr('href'), "_blank");
};
```